# JavaScript display fetched object in html table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fetch function that looks like this

```js
let url = 'someurl.com';
var dataObject_ = [];

fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(output => {
        var huj = output;
        // console.log(huj);
        dataObject_.push.apply(dataObject, huj);
    }
);
console.log(huj) outputs -> Array(10)
0: {wine_country: "France", wine_name: "Lafite Rothschild", wine_region: "Bordeaux Premier Cru - left bank", wine_year: 2016}
1: {wine_country: "France", wine_name: "Lafite Rothschild", wine_region: "Bordeaux Premier Cru - left bank", wine_year: 2000}
etc...
```

and I have table that looks like that

```js
var hotSettings = {
  data: dataObject_,
  columns: [
    {
      data: 'wine_name',
      type: 'text'
    },

    {
      data: 'wine_year',
      type: 'numeric'
    },
    {
      data: 'wine_region',
      type: 'text'
    },
      {
      data: 'wine_country',
      type: 'text'
    },
  ],
  stretchH: 'all',
  width: 805,
  autoWrapRow: true,
  height: 487,
  maxRows: 22,
  manualRowResize: true,
  manualColumnResize: true,
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: [
    'Wine',
    'Year',
    'Region',
    'Country'
  ],
  manualRowMove: true,
  manualColumnMove: true,
  contextMenu: true,
  filters: true,
  dropdownMenu: true
};
```

My goal is to use `dataObject_` to display it in the table. When I create a variable and just copypaste json from API it works fine, but when I get data from API call and push it to the array it doesnt output it somehow. I tried different ways of doing it, nothing works. The JSON itself looks like this

```
  {
    "wine_country": "France",
    "wine_name": "Petrus",
    "wine_region": "Bordeaux Pomerols - right bank",
    "wine_year": 1990
  },
  {
    "wine_country": "France",
    "wine_name": "Petrus",
    "wine_region": "Bordeaux Pomerols - right bank",
    "wine_year": 1989
  }
```

I am sorry, i am a completely beginner in JavaScript / front-end and if this looks ridiculous

Comment: What is the output of console.log(huj) when you fetch from the API ?

Comment: @alchemist95 Array(10)
with the correct API response of 10 objects inside of it

Comment: Try doing Array.prototype.push.apply(dataObject, huj)

Comment: @alchemist95 Didn't help unfortunately :(

Comment: Got it. You should do Array.prototype.push.apply(hotSettings.data, huj)
That's because hotSettings has already been stored in memory. hotSettings.data won't update because of change in dataObject_, that's because while writing to memory, only the value was taken from dataObject_.

Comment: @alchemist95 you are correct 100%, BUT it somehow doesnt output it :/
when I ```console.log(hotSettings.data);``` it outputs Array(10) same as commented in a fucntion, but doesnt render it for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215685/discussion-between-alchemist95-and-nexla).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, once you define variable `g`, that gets stored in global memory with the value that `h` has. It won't update once h changes because it has no idea what h is. It was only concerned about the value it was holding while initialization.

[image]